# How does recursion get previous values?

Tags: c++

I'm in the basic of the basic of learning c++, and ran into an example of recursion that I don't understand. The equation is for Fibonacci numbers, and is shown below:

```
int fibo(int f)
{
    if (f < 3)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return fibo(f - 2) + fibo(f - 1);
    }
}
```

How does the "else" statement work? I know that it adds the two previous numbers to get the current fibbonacci number, but how does it know, without any prior information, where to start? If I want the 7th fibonacci number, how does it know what the 6th and 5th numbers are?

Comment: Try walking through the algorithm with pen and paper. Don't try to understand it, just by staring at it.

Comment: If you are new to programming, learning recursion by computing the Fibonacci sequence is rough :)

Comment: I think the best way to start is to learn to use your debugger; and understand what `fibo(1)` does.  Then `fibo(2)`.  then `fibo(3)`.  Learning to use your debugger is THE most important lesson for programming; and I wouldn't bother attempting to teach people anything more complex than how to write a function if they don't know that.  Honestly, it's really that important

Comment: *how does it know what is the 2 values that come before so it can sum and get my value, without any posterior information?* -- You may not realize it, but your realization about "posterior information" is interesting.  A better (i.e. faster) Fibonacci recursive function *would* save prior information for later use in computing the series, as you suspected.

Comment: It doesn't know what the values are. It just class itself twice with different values. If the recursion function was bad, you could easily get an infinite loop or burn up your stack memory. In this case the condition f < 3 acts as the stop criteria. Also this implementation of recursion is very slow, like n^2 operations to compute f(n).

Comment: Thank you guys for clarifying me, now i understand it much better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive function will call itself as many times as it needs to compute the final value. For example, if you call `fibo(3)`, it will call itself with `fibo(2)` and `fibo(1)`.

You can understand it better if you write down a tree representing all the function calls (the numbers in brackets are the return values):

```
       fibo(3) [1+1]
          |
    .--------------.
    |              |
fibo(2) [1]    fibo(1) [1]
```

For `fibo(7)`, you will have multple calls like so:

```
                             fibo(7) [fibo(6) + fibo(5)]
                                |
              .-----------------------------------------------.
              |                                               |
           fibo(6) [fibo(5) + fibo(4)]                      fibo(5) [fibo(4) + fibo(3)]
              |                                               |
     .---------------------------------.                     ...
     |                                 | 
fibo(5) [fibo(4) + fibo(3)]        fibo(4) [fibo(3) + fibo(2)]
     |                                 |
    ...                               ...
```

Each recursive call will execute the same code, but with a different value of `f`. And each recursive call will have to call their own "editions" of the sub-cases (smaller values). This happens until everyone reaches the base case (`f < 3`).

I didn't draw the entire tree. But I guess you can see this grows very quick. There's a lot of repetition (`fibo(7)` calls `fibo(6)` and `fibo(5`), then `fibo(6)` calls `fibo(5)` again). This is why we usually don't implement Fibonacci recursively, except for studying recursion.

Answer (score 4):

In this given equation, It will go deeper in the root. When you have given Value 7 initially, it will go to function itself to get value of 7-2 = 5 and 7-1=6, still its has not value of 5 and 6. so further it will decrease value of 5 to 3 and 4 and 6 to 5 and 4.
at the end when f is less then 3 it will return value 1. something like that after getting root values it will sum up those values to get total answer.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/  || Go to geeksforgeeks to more information

Comment: *Go to geeksforgeeks to more information* --  Maybe for algorithms, but don't go to that site if you want to learn how to properly write C++.  At that page, this is used: `int f[n+2];` -- This is not proper C++, as arrays must have their sizes denoted by a constant, not a variable expression.  That should be `std::vector<int> f(n+2);`